# i3wm with libinput-gestures

Tags: touchpad, startup, i3-wm, libinput, gestures

I have googled for 2 days but I did not find my answer. I have a working config file for the libinput-gestures. Since a few days I am switched to i3wm. So far it looks good enough, only the libinput-gestures autostart does not work. When I start libinput from the terminal:

```
    libinput-gestures-setup autostart
    libinput-gestures-setup start
```

everything works fine.

I tried to put a command in the i3 config file. Below a list of command I tried so far

```
    exec --no-startup-id libinput-gestures-setup start
    exec --no-startup-id /home/pepijn/i3_script.sh &
    exec --no-startup-id /home/pepijn/i3_script.sh 
    exec --no-startup-id "/home/pepijn/i3_script.sh"
    exec --no-startup-id "bash /home/pepijn/i3_script.sh"
```

I tried som other command I do not remember at the moment, but none worked so far.

The script looks as follow:

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash
    libinput-gestures-setup autostart
    libinput-gestures-setup start
```

The script worked when it is called from the terminal.

Has somebody experience how to start libinput using i3?

Comment: Try `exec --no-startup-id "sudo libinput-gestures-setup start"`. Check the i3 logs : `i3-dump-log` for more information.

Comment: Mayby try introducing a short delay before the command is xecuted, i.e., "sleep 3 && libinput..."

Comment: I tried both methods, also in combination (with sudo and with a delay). It did not work. Now I just run my script manually after the startup. 
When I have more time I will look for the i3-logs to see what I can find in there.

Comment: I currently use i3wm in combination with plasma. The autostart of plasma provides the libinput-gestures-setup. I know this is a work around, but it works. I think i3wm in combination with plasma works just fine, although a little bit slower of course. Thanks for your answers.